# How to Sync Django HTTP Login Session with Websocket Session/Cookie?

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels, graphene-python

I am using Django DjangoChannelsGraphqlWs which is Graphene version of Django Channels. (https://github.com/datadvance/DjangoChannelsGraphqlWs) It allows me to transfer data using graphql style. I wrote a login login on my mutation schema.

```
class Login(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        email = graphene.String()
        password = graphene.String()

    ok = graphene.Boolean()
    user = graphene.Field(UserType)

    def mutate(root, info, email, password, **kwargs):
        ok = False
        user = authenticate(info.context, username=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(info.context, user)
            update_or_create_user_login_info(info=info)
            ok = True
            return Login(ok=ok, user=user)
        else:
            return Login(ok=ok)
```

And I wrote my client side Websocket using Apollo-client like this:

```
class WebSocketService {
    static instance = null;
    callbacks = {};

    static getInstance() {
        if (!WebSocketService.instance)
            WebSocketService.instance = new WebSocketService();
        return WebSocketService.instance;
    }

    constructor() {
        this.socketRef = null;
        this.connect();
    }

    connect() {
        const client = new SubscriptionClient(BASE_URL + '/graphql/', {
            reconnect: true,
        });
        const link = new WebSocketLink(client);
        const cache = new InMemoryCache();

        this.socketRef = new ApolloClient({
            link,
            cache,
        });
    }

    query = (query, variables={}, context={}, fetchPolicy='no-cache', errorPolicy='all') =>
        this.socketRef.query({
            query: gql`${query}`,
            variables,
            context,
            fetchPolicy,
            errorPolicy
        })

    mutate = (mutation, variables={}, context={}, fetchPolicy='no-cache', errorPolicy='all') =>
        this.socketRef.mutate({
            mutation: gql`${mutation}`,
            variables,
            context,
            fetchPolicy,
            errorPolicy
        })
}

const WebSocketInstance = WebSocketService.getInstance();

export default WebSocketInstance;
```

Lastly, here is my consumer.

```
class MyGraphqlWsConsumer(channels_graphql_ws.GraphqlWsConsumer):
    """Channels WebSocket consumer which provides GraphQL API."""
    schema = schema
    send_keepalive_every = 60
```

I attempted to log in using the WebSocketInstance. However, Django's login function fails when I hand over info.context and authenticate(info.context, user) parameters. It throws error saying "types.SimpleNamespace' object has no attirbute 'META'". After stumbling upon with the error, I gave up with logging in with a websocket and decided to just use axios and normal http request.

But here is another issue. The session and cookies are not synced. When I use axios and normal http request, the login itself does work well, but websocket connection does not reflect the logged in session/cookies.

I found that it takes some time to reflect the change and it happens after disconnecting and reconnecting the websocket.

How should I sync the login information?

Comment: could you at least link the channels graphene lib you're using?

Comment: @Ken4scholars I added the link on the post! https://github.com/datadvance/DjangoChannelsGraphqlWs

Comment: @Beginner, have you checked [the Authentication section](https://github.com/datadvance/DjangoChannelsGraphqlWs#authentication) of the DjangoChannelsGraphqlWs docs?

Comment: @prokher Yes I did. I am still using this library. It is a very good library. I decided to log users in by normal Django login function because I wanted to make users' sessions persist. On the client side, I have to reconnect Websocket, if there was a previously connected one. If I close and reconnect Websocket, it works pretty well. Thanks for replying to an old question :)

Comment: @Beginner As for me you describe quite decent auth implementation. Indeed, in the software I am in charge of we use both native Django's session-based auth and token-based auth for WebSocket, we also have to store this token in the browser's local storage to make it persistent. Otherwise client will have to reauthorize each time he refreshes the page.

Comment: @prokher Oh, I initially considered JWT based authentication, but I found many critics saying that localstorage is not an ideal place to secure the token. And I did not know where else to save the token if it is not localstorage. Furthermore, I cannot revoke the token unless I save the validity of the token somewhere, so it becomes the same as session-based authentication. Lke sessions, I have to access to the data every time I validate the token, although I currently use Redis cache backend for session instead of Model backend. I needed to revoke the token when users change their passwords.

Answer (score 0):

try overing the graphl_jwt

```
class ObtainJSONWebToken(graphql_jwt.JSONWebTokenMutation):
    user = graphene.Field(UserType)
    session = graphene.String()

    @classmethod
    def resolve(cls, root, info, **kwargs):
    user=info.context.user
    if user:
        login(info.context,user)
        session=info.context.session
        session.save()
    
        if session.session_key:
        #print(session.session_key)
        return cls(user=user,session=session.session_key)
        else:
        raise Exception('try it again')
```

in mutation

```
class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):
    token_auth=ObtainJSONWebToken.Field()
```